# Why ZeroMQ C# PUB/SUB throws an EINVAL warning on pgm-protocol?

Tags: c#, zeromq, publish-subscribe, pgm-protocol

I am completely new to ZeroMQ, my Window C# application is going to publish data through ( `tcp://localhost:5563` ), if I change it to ( `pgm://localhost;233.255.0.1:5555` ), throws an error:

> EINVAL(22): Invalid argument
>
> Warn: Interface {xxx-xxx-xxx..-xxx} reports as a loopback device.

Anyone can give some hints?

Answer (score 0):

<sup>A use of `epgm://<IPv4_ADDR>;<mcast_ADDR>:<port#>` is advised in ZeroMQ API documentation.</sup>

### ZeroMQ API documentation remarks are all important:

> **Connecting a socket**
>   When connecting a socket to a peer address using ***zmq_connect()*** with the ***pgm*** or ***epgm*** transport, the ***endpoint*** shall be interpreted as an ***interface*** followed by a semicolon, followed by a ***multicast address***, followed by a colon and a port number.
>   An interface may be specified by either of the following:
>    - The interface name as defined by the operating system.
>    - The primary IPv4 address assigned to the interface, in its numeric representation.

---

> Interface names are not standardised in any way and should be assumed to be arbitrary and platform dependent. On Win32 platforms **no short interface names exist, thus only the primary IPv4 address may be used to specify an interface**. The interface part can be omitted, in that case the default one will be selected.
>   A multicast address is specified by an IPv4 multicast address in its numeric representation.